# Spark Submit job in databricks UI unable to access existing Hive DB

Tags: apache-spark, hive, databricks, azure-databricks

I created a spark submit job in databricks to run a .py script. I created a spark object in my python script. I tried to access existing Hive Tables. But my script fails with "Table or view not found" error. Should I add some configuration settings in my spark submit job to connect to existing hive metastore?

Comment: Please include which spark version and sample code on how you are trying to access the `hive` tables. i will help people in answering your questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try using like below while creating spark Session in spark 2.0+

```
spark = SparkSession.builder.enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate()
```

This will usually solve these kind of errors